# Stop GTM encoding '==' in string constant

Tags: google-tag-manager

When I inject this example GTM tag on a site the '==' in the src string is encoded as \x3d\x3d which fails to resolve. Is there a way to stop the encoding?

GTM tag:

`<script type="text/javascript"> !function(o,t){var src="https://test@testsite.com/test/1MmE5ZDA4ZGExODZkOTQifQ==/assets/demo.js";
...
</script>`

on page:

`<script type="text/javascript"> !function(o,t){var src="https://test@testsite.com/test/1MmE5ZDA4ZGExODZkOTQifQ\x3d\x3d/assets/demo.js";
...
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to insert an src into an iframe.  I was populating the query string with GTM variables that contained "=" but they would get encoded as %3D.

My solution was injecting the HTML tag on the page using Javascript instead.

OLD WAY (HTML)

```
<iframe height="1" width="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.something.com/?containerTagId={{containerID}}"></iframe>
```

NEW WAY (JAVASCRIPT)

```
<script>
var script = document.createElement('iframe');
script.height="1";
script.width="1";
script.frameborder="0";
script.scrolling="no";
script.name="conversion";
script.src = 'https://www.something.com/?containerTagId={{containerID}}';
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```